# Unable to load Hunspell package

Tags: python, hunspell

I have installed hunspell 1.6 in python 3.5 environment using conda. When I try to import, it gives a import error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'hunspell'
```

Here is the screenshot attached.

[Hunspell Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPB6B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on Linux? In my case the installation of missing packages helped:

```
sudo apt install python-dev libhunspell-dev
```

Can you add more info like the output of

```
conda list hunspell
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the package [CyHunspell](https://github.com/MSeal/cython_hunspell) which is regularly maintained:

`pip install cyhunspell` (currently not available via conda repositories)

(It appears that [PyHunspell](https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell) (`pip install hunspell` or `conda install hunspell`) is no longer maintained, last commit 2 years ago, and very hacky to get working.)

Requires `gcc` (on Ubuntu: `sudo apt install build-essentials` if you don't already have it).